# Block Game: Dynamic vs Greedy approach

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

This is a question from an old exam in a Combinatorial Algorithms class, I am reviewing for a midterm. I understand the game but I don't understand the "optimal" approach, ie. implementing a Dynamic programming approach (versus a greedy approach). If somebody would be so kind as to explain the dynamic (optimal) approach it would be greatly appreciated. Answers are given at the bottom. Apologies for the long post.

**Brick Game:**

Suppose there is a stack of n bricks. The ith brick in the stack is worth v[i] points (where v[0] is the value of the top brick). The players take turns removing either 1 or 2 bricks from the top of the stack. The player that removes a brick earns the number of points associated with the brick. The game ends when all the bricks have been removed, and the winner is the player who has earned the most points.

For example, if v = [1, 1, 3, 4] and Player A is the first player to move, then A’s optimal strategy is to take just the first brick (earning 1 point). Player B's optimal strategy is then to take the next two bricks (earning 4 points). A then finishes by taking the last brick (earning 4 more points).  Therefore, the maximum score A can earn is 5.

Suppose v = [2, -2, 5, 8, -15, 3, 8, 30, 2, 10, -40]
Assume that A takes the first turn and that both A and B play optimally.

1. Fill in the answers to the sub problems left blank in the table below; these entries in the third column show the value of the game up to height k for whomever's turn it is at this point.
2. Next propose a simple yet plausible greedy strategy for Player A. Show if it fails to result in an optimal final score or actually produces an optimal score.

| k | v[k] | s[k] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | -2 |  |
| 2 | 5 |  |
| 3 | 8 |  |
| 4 | -15 |  |
| 5 | 3 |  |
| 6 | 8 |  |
| 7 | 30 |  |
| 8 | 2 | 12 |
| 9 | 10 | 10 |
| 10 | -40 | -40 |

**The answers as provided by the answer key:**

A greedy approach would choose whichever yielded more at each choice-one block or two.
In our problem the optimal strategy guarantees 28, with the opponent getting -17.  The greedy approach nets only 8, and the opponent gets 3.

To be more specific, the optimal strategy (with optimal counterplay) selects, in order from top, the values (2, 8, 8, 10).  The greedy grabs (2, 8, 38, -40).

Answer (score 2):

Since the game is zero-sum and impartial, the value of a move is the immediate gain *minus* the optimal value of the resulting state. The optimal $s_k$ can thus be calculated backwards as
$$s_k=\max(v_k-s_{k+1},v_k+v_{k+1}-s_{k+2})=v_k-\min(s_{k+1},s_{k+2}-v_{k+1})$$
This gives

| $k$ | $v_k$ | $s_k$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | $45_1$ |
| 1 | -2 | $-43_2$ |
| 2 | 5 | $51_2$ |
| 3 | 8 | $46_1$ |
| 4 | -15 | $-38_2$ |
| 5 | 3 | $29_2$ |
| 6 | 8 | $26_1$ |
| 7 | 30 | $-18_2$ |
| 8 | 2 | $52_2$ |
| 9 | 10 | $50_1$ |
| 10 | -40 | $-40_1$ |

The subscript indicates the optimal number of bricks to take in the corresponding game state; it is a byproduct of calculating the $s_k$.